# How to use sap.m.ViewSettingsDialog in a sap.suite.ui.commons.Timeline as a custom filter?

Tags: javascript, filter, sapui5

Currently, I want to integrate a multi-faceted filter in a sap.suite.ui.commons.Timeline, as it is described in the [Fiori Design Guidelines](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/timeline/#filter-optional). The guidelines say, that one have to use a sap.m.ViewSettingsDialog for it.

Looking into the [Timeline API](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.suite.ui.commons.Timeline/aggregations) says, that there exists an aggregation *customFilter*, but the control used inside *needs to have* an *openBy* function, which is called to open the custom filter popover / dialog.

My problem now is, that the *sap.m.ViewSettingsDialog* does not have a *openBy* function, but only (since it is a dialog, the [API description](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.ViewSettingsDialog/methods/Summary) reflects it) an *open()* function.

How do I correctly implement a multi-faceted filter by using the ViewSettingsDialog?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three options:

1. Use a different Popover (e.g. [ResponsivePopover](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.ResponsivePopover/overview)).
2. Hide the filter bar button by setting the `showTimeFilter` and `showItemFilter` to false and than add your own button with whatever logic you need:

   ```
   oTimeline.getHeaderBar().addContent(new Button({
       press: function () {
         oViewSettingDialog.open();
       }
   });
   ```
3. You can extend the `sap.m.ViewSettingsDialog` to add an `openBy` method which will just call `open`. It can be done statically:

   ```
   var CustomViewSettingDialog = ViewSettingDialog.extend("my.namespace.CustomViewSettingDialog", {
     openBy: function () {
       this.open();
     }
   });
   ```

   Or in runtime:

   ```
   var oViewSettingDialog = new ViewSettingDialog(...);
   oViewSettingDialog.openBy = function () {
     this.open();
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this overview. I feared the answer would look like this :-) My hope was, that there is some _official_ I missed until now...

Comment: If it's still of any use for you, starting from 1.58 ViewSettingDialog and all components with open method will be supported out of the box.